# HTML is not being updated properly on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create flashcards that display 4 cards at a time. The cards are populated with an object array. One button shows the next four cards and another shows the last four cards. Currently, the button that shows the last four cards needs pressed twice in order to work. Once the user wants to go forward again, they need to press the button twice again. I am not sure why this is occurring.

Here is my code:

```js
var cardWords = [{
    word: 'one 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'two 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'three 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'four 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'one 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'two 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'three 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'four 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'one 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'two 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'three 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'four 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'one 4',
    deck: 4
  },
  {
    word: 'two 4',
    deck: 4
  },
  {
    word: 'three 4',
    deck: 4
  },
  {
    word: 'four 4',
    deck: 4
  }
];

var i = 0;

// REVIEW: : On first click, show first four, on second click show second four, etc.
function nextGroup() {

  console.log(i);

  if (i == cardWords.length) { //Before displaying cards, reset i if i == cardWords.length; If i == cardWords.length, we're at the end
    i = 0;
    console.log(i, "reset")
  }

  document.getElementById('showWord').innerHTML = cardWords[i].word; //First card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord1').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 1].word; //Second card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord2').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 2].word; //Third card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord3').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 3].word; //Fourth card of deck

  if (i < cardWords.length) { //Place after displaying to not skip first four
    i = i + 4; //Add by 4 to get index of first card in next deck
    console.log(i);
  }

}

function lastGroup() {

  console.log(i);

  if (i != 0) { //Place after displaying to not skip first four
    i = i - 4; //Decrease by 4 to get index of first card in previous deck
    console.log(i);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('showWord').innerHTML = cardWords[i].word; //First card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord1').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 1].word; //Second card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord2').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 2].word; //Third card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord3').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 3].word; //Fourth card of deck

}
```

```css
.card {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: floralwhite;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <div id="showWord" class="card">Learned Words</div>
    <input type="button" value="Next Group" onclick="nextGroup()">
    <input type="button" value="Last Group" onclick="lastGroup()">
  </div>

  <div id="showWord1" class="card">Words</div>
  <div id="showWord2" class="card">Words</div>
  <div id="showWord3" class="card">Words</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: You're adding 4 at the end of next and subtracting 4 at the end of last so they are showing the same group. "Previous" is clearer for this purpose than "Last". If you use a flag to determine whether to do the initial increment on the first press you should be fine. I'll write it up.

Answer (score 0):

The incrementing and decrementing should happen when you hit the button, not as a side effect of the previous press. I'm using the modulo operator here to handle wrapping around to zero when you overflow past the max or vice versa. It's a little "cute" but common enough. It can be though of as the remainder of dividing by the total number of cards by the index in this case.

```
i = ( i + 4 ) % cardWords.length;
```

Take the current index up by 4 and then make sure that number is in the range of available cards.

```
i = ( i - 4 + cardWords.length ) % cardWords.length;
```

Take the current index down by 4, make sure it stays positive by adding the total number of cards, and then make sure that number is in the range of available cards.

```js
var cardWords = [{
    word: 'one 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'two 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'three 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'four 1',
    deck: 1
  },
  {
    word: 'one 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'two 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'three 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'four 2',
    deck: 2
  },
  {
    word: 'one 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'two 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'three 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'four 3',
    deck: 3
  },
  {
    word: 'one 4',
    deck: 4
  },
  {
    word: 'two 4',
    deck: 4
  },
  {
    word: 'three 4',
    deck: 4
  },
  {
    word: 'four 4',
    deck: 4
  }
];

var i = 0;
var firstTurn = true;

// REVIEW: : On first click, show first four, on second click show second four, etc.
function nextGroup() {

  i = (i + 4) % cardWords.length;

  if (firstTurn) {
    i = 0;
    firstTurn = false;
  }

  console.log(i);

  document.getElementById('showWord').innerHTML = cardWords[i].word; //First card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord1').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 1].word; //Second card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord2').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 2].word; //Third card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord3').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 3].word; //Fourth card of deck

}

function lastGroup() {

  i = (i - 4 + cardWords.length) % cardWords.length;

  console.log(i);

  document.getElementById('showWord').innerHTML = cardWords[i].word; //First card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord1').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 1].word; //Second card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord2').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 2].word; //Third card of deck
  document.getElementById('showWord3').innerHTML = cardWords[i + 3].word; //Fourth card of deck

}
```

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <div>
    <div id="showWord" class="card">Learned Words</div>
    <input type="button" value="Next Group" onclick="nextGroup()">
    <input type="button" value="Last Group" onclick="lastGroup()">
  </div>

  <div id="showWord1" class="card">Words</div>
  <div id="showWord2" class="card">Words</div>
  <div id="showWord3" class="card">Words</div>

</body>

</html>
```